# lodash orderBy issues when trying to make it case insensitive

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I've written this `orderBy` condition to short an object array and it works fine unless the value that I am trying to sort is null. Below you can see my code:

```
if (this.state.sortType === 'name asc'){
  medias = _.orderBy(medias,[media  => _.get(media,'metadata.title').toString().toLowerCase() ] , 'asc')
} else if (this.state.sortType === 'name desc'){
  medias = _.orderBy(medias, [media  => _.get(media,'metadata.title').toString().toLowerCase()], 'desc')
}
```

When `media.metadata.title` is `null` it throws that error:

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your input data? It seems like some of the elements don't have a `metadata: { title: "" }` property

Comment: Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5, toString() called on null returns [object Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined], as defined in the 5th Edition of ECMAScript and a subsequent Errata. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: @SibasishMohanty that's a behaviour I've never seen, nor does it currently work. This is either not worded correctly or completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not take a default value of [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get), like an empty string in case metadata is not present in media object.

> ```
> _.get(object, path, [defaultValue])
> ```

```
_.get(media,'metadata.title', '').toString()
```

Comment: [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) already provides for a default value. Just pass it in the third parameter `_.get(media, 'metadata.title', '')`